# How to change the radio button or checkbox layout

Tags: html, jsf, richfaces

We use [h:selectManyCheckbox](http://www.exadel.com/tutorial/jsf/jsftags-guide.html) and [h:selectOneRadio](http://www.exadel.com/tutorial/jsf/jsftags-guide.html) for rendering choices against a certain element. We would like the flexibility to layout the choices either horizontally, vertically or sorted in multiple columns.

```
e.g. 
1. Horizontally
one two three four five six

2. Vertically
one 
two
three
four
five
six

3. 2 columns
one two
three four
five six

4. 3 columns
one two three
four five six
```

How do we accomplish this either using the existing jsf tags or with suitable changes.

Comment: I think custom JSF ui components or a custom jsp tag is a solution for you...

Comment: formatted text to make it more clear

Comment: for the 1st and second questions , you can use layout attribute like   layout="lineDirection" or layout="pageDirection" inside those jsf tags.

Comment: @khairil - yes we are aware that 1,2 are solved by default, we are interested in solving 3,4 along with the existing support

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use  from apache tomahawk library with layoutWidth property. Or create your own JSF component

Comment: Using Tomahawk's the `t:selectOneRadio` with `layoutWidth` property is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, be clear in what you want...
2. Take a look at: [Developing a custom JSF tag](http://j2eedocument.appspot.com/2009/10/section-93-developing-a-custom-jsf-tag.html)
3. Know what attributes you can pass in your new custom tag, example (`<h:customRadioButtons list="arraylist" style="table" name="rbuttons" columns="2" />`)
4. Develope your future customTag...

Answer (score 0):

using tomahawk ,we can try use layout="spread" like:

```
 <t:selectOneRadio id="test" value="one" layout="spread" border="1">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="one" itemValue="one" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="two" itemValue="two" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="three" itemValue="three" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="four" itemValue="four" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="five" itemValue="five" />      
  </t:selectOneRadio>
  <t:panelGrid columns="2">
    <t:radio for="test" index="0"></t:radio>
    <t:radio for="test" index="1"></t:radio>
  </t:panelGrid>
  <t:panelGrid columns="3">
    <t:radio for="test" index="2"></t:radio>                
    <t:radio for="test" index="3"></t:radio>
    <t:radio for="test" index="4"></t:radio>
  </t:panelGrid>
```

then use ajax to rerender this t:selectOneRadio to change to other layout.

Comment: we don't use tomahawk, we use richfaces along with Mojarra (Sun's RI)

Answer (score -2):

You can make facelate for this and customize your layout by using  and bind with Mybean containing id, value, checked....